# Escape from gravitational field

Tags: homework-and-exercises

Why total energy of a spacecraft must be non-negative if we want spacecraft to escape from the Earth's gravitational field?

Comment: For the same reason that it costs you energy to move up a staircase.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: You need a positive energy to escape the ground floor and reach the attic of your house. To get further away from earth than your attic requires even more energy.

Comment: @Johannes Thanks. Explanation for all those who wants more specific answer on my question [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity)

Comment: you just need to same energy to escape the gravitational  as much it is needed and any extra will provide you further motion in the space like you need to pay the amount of just the item you bought from the supermarket but you need extra money to take a taxi and go home but if you don't have extra money you cant get away from the shop (assuming you can move without a taxi) but still you will own the items you purchase did you got it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is because we simply(and in some cases arbitrarily) put the zero of the potential at infinity. When integrating the gravitational force to obtain its potential, a constant appears, which in most cases is fixed by zeroing the infinity's potential. This means that if an object is stationary(no kinetic energy) at infinity(no potential energy) the total energy will be zero. So for an object to reach infinity, its energy should be greater than zero(conservation of energy).